# Smallest nonzero singular value of a product of two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

all.

For a matrix $\mathbf{M}$, let $\sigma_{\min}(\mathbf{M})$ denote the smallest $\textit{nonzero}$ singular value of $\mathbf{M}$.

Then, does the following inequality hold true?
\begin{align}
\sigma_{\min}(\mathbf{A} \mathbf{B}) \ge \sigma_{\min}(\mathbf{A}) \sigma_{\min}(\mathbf{B})
\end{align}
Here, $\mathbf{A}$ does not have full column rank and $\mathbf{B}$ has full column rank.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No. Consider, e.g. $A=\pmatrix{1&0}$ and $B=\pmatrix{0\\ 1}$. We have $\sigma_\min(AB)=0$, but $\sigma_\min(A)\sigma_\min(B)=1\times1=1$.

However, the answer to your question is yes if $A$ is "tall" (i.e. if $A$ has at least as many rows as columns). In this case, as $A$ also assumed to have deficient column rank, $\sigma_\min(A)$ becomes zero and the inequality follows.

Comment: $\sigma_\text{min}$ is never zero, by definition.

Comment: Instead, let $B = \begin{pmatrix} 1/\sqrt2 \\ 1/\sqrt2 \end{pmatrix}$.